# How do I make a command that works on 2 or more channels

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm new to coding and I was trying to make a command that only works on 2 or more channels but I don't know the code for it.

How do I make a command that only works on 2 or more channels?

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any errors? What code do you have already? Please explain the problem clearly and show as much detail as you can.

Comment: I've tried ```client.on('message', msg => { if (msg.channel.id === 'channel id here') { }}};``` and it worked but it only works one channel there was no error it worked but i wanted know if i could do it in 2 or more channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an array containing a list of desired channels contains the current channel:

```js
if ([/* channel IDs */].includes(message.channel.id)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use channel names instead:

```js
if ([/* channel names */].includes(message.channel.name)) {
  // do stuff
}
```